# ASP.NET MVC 4 Read through cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, locking

I have a system which sits on a web server and generates files on the fly in response to HTTP requests.  The system is built using asp.net mvc 4. All the code is in controller. Once the files are generated, they don't change very often, so I'd like to implement a cache .  How can I implement the below ?
User 1 requested document 1 --- web server the processing is going  on… meanwhile User 2 requested document 1 ( same document).. I don’t want to start generating document 1 second time.. I would like this request to wait until the user1 request is completed so that user 2 request can be served from cache. This may just basic problem… I want to understand the solution before I implement caching.
Please help with some samples..

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple solution would be to cache a [`Lazy<MyType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) instance, where `MyType` is the Type that represents your document.

For the scenario you describe, you should construct your `Lazy<MyType>` instance using `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`.  This will ensure that the document is generated only once.